# Is it necessary to store a Date object created with "new" in a variable?

Tags: javascript, object

Is it OK to do this:

```
var t = (new Date()).getTime();
```

Or creating an object like that is bad? In theory it shouldn't be, because it's not referenced and the garbage collector can remove it, right?

If it's not OK, do I have to do something like this:

```
var d = new Date(),
    t = d.getTime();
d = null;
```

Comment: __It is all right...__

Comment: What do you mean by _`it's not referenced and the garbage collector can remove it`_?

Comment: Well, as far as I know, an object can be removed only when it's not referenced by any other object or variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is fine to create an object and not store it.  An object that is created and then not referenced further or stored will be eligible for garbage collection right away.

But, rather than create that object, I'd suggest you just use the static method for getting the current time:

```
var t = Date.now()
```

There is no need to even create a Date object just to get the current time (except in really old versions of IE).  If you are supporting IE8, then you could just use this polyfill in your project so `Date.now()` will work there too:

```
if (!Date.now) {
  Date.now = function() {
    return new Date().getTime();
  };
}
```

Comment: Same story with Node.js?

Comment: @HristiyanDodov yes except node.js doesn't need the polyfill.

Comment: @HristiyanDodov - The GC issue is the same in node.js.  node.js always has `Date.now()` so you should just use that in node.js.

Answer (score 1):

Either is fine, `getTime()` returns a `Number` and so doesn't count in the refcount. The object will be GCed in both cases.

However, as said in the comments, you can just use `Date.now()` for a clearer bit of code:

```js
console.log((new Date()).getTime() === Date.now());
```

Answer (score 0):

It is totally OK to create and use an object on the fly.

However if you want to create temporary variable as in your second example, your are not forced to explicitelly  set It to null. As long as your variable is not actively referenced somewhere else in your code it will be garbage collected.